# What does the property "Enable Streaming" in SqlBulkCopy do exactly in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to understand how `SqlBulkCopy` works, and as I read in the Microsoft docs,

> when `EnableStreaming` is true, SqlBulkCopy reads from an IDataReader object using SequentialAccess, optimizing memory usage by using the IDataReader streaming capabilities. When it's set to false, the `SqlBulkCopy` class loads all the data returned by the `IDataReader` object into memory before sending it to SQL Server or SQL Azure.

If that's the case, why don't we use it always?

If it's not, in which cases we have to turn it off (which is the default) and on?

Comment: Not streaming a 2 GB blob would be a bad idea. On the other hand, streaming a lot of tiny rows column by column as opposed to first gathering all the data could also be a bad idea. Ultimately you really want to test and see. In practice, when not actually streaming blobs, I've found this option to make precious little difference as opposed to all the other things you do to optimize bulk inserting (heap tables, packet size, etc.)

Comment: Microsoft has updated their documentation somewhere* to clarify "The streaming capabilities are only enabled for large data sets (i.e.
only when value type is the same size as the max length) and when the SqlDataReader row source is null." * -  I do not see any changes in [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.enablestreaming?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0&viewFallbackFrom=net-8.0) but there is a competed [GitHub request](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1873) to update them.